# Combining group of arrays and minimize resulting negative elements

Tags: python, arrays, python-itertools, minimize

Problem:

> Given a set of **G** groups, each of them with a set of **n_i**
> int-arrays with a fixed length **t**:
>
> Find the combinations of arrays (variable length, from 1 to G), so the
> resulting sum-array contains the minimum number of negative elements.

For example:

- Group 1: [-4,1,8], [-2,4,6], [2,6,-6], [-4,10,-1]
- Group 2: [-1,3,6], [0,3,0]
- Group 3: [2,-1,2], [3,4,5], [0,4,-3]
- Group 4: [-2,-1,2], [-3,0,1]

We can combine only up to one array of each group. In this example, one possible combination would be:

- Group 1 -> [-2,4,6]
- Group 2 -> [0,3,0]
- Group 3 -> [3,4,5]
- Group 4 -> None

Resulting in a sum-vector: [1,11,11], which has no negative elements. As you can see, none of the arrays from Group 4 has been taken into the solution.

I´ve been trying to do this with itertools and numpy arrays in Python, but I am running out of memory when I have > 150 arrays in ~ 9 different groups.

I am not asking for a piece of code to solve this, but rather, if this problem has a name or if you know what would be the best way to solve it, considering that I will need to solve it for a larger number of arrays and groups (around 15_000 arrays and 20 groups) and my memory is limited to around 60GB.

I know I can iterate directly in itertool.combinations so I don't need to "build" the whole list of combinations; that would solve my memory issues I guess, but still I wonder if there is a more efficient way to tackle this problem instead of evaluating all possible combinations, which could be billions at the end.

Do you have any idea? Am I approaching this problem in the right way? Is there any library to solve this actually?

Comment: Please, provide your current solution. Also, add a sample if input and expected output

Comment: Because each group has many arrays, and they can be combined with the arrays of the rest of the groups.

Comment: I have added an example. Please consider that the number of arrays in each group is much larger and also the number of groups.

Comment: I see, the specification was not clear enough. The groups may have different number of arrays, which I have represented now with "n_i". Given the example below, maybe now the problem is more clear.

Comment: _"We can combine only up to one array of each group."_ Trivial solution: don't take any array that has a negative number. The solution will always have no negative numbers.